# Fstrim version and usage

Tags: linux, executable, version, fstrim

I have one fstrim executable file and need a way of finding that executable file version.

Comment: How was it installed? From source or through a package manager?

Answer (score 1):

`fstrim --version` will tell you:

```
$ /sbin/fstrim --version
fstrim from util-linux 2.29.2
```

You can then ask your package manager for the exact package version (assuming your binary was installed using the package manager):

```
$ dpkg -l util-linux
$ rpm -q util-linux
```

etc. (depending on your distribution).